# php is sending invalid email address

Tags: php, html, forms, email

Hello after 3 days of trying to put my form together, I have come across a problem...
Using the form, It can validate when i press submit. which is good, but once i press send, the invalid data still gets sent to my inbox.. so I will end up with two emails.. one with invalid data and then one with the valid data which is typed in after the error messages have been displayed and re-sent.  If anyone can look at my code and see what I am missing, or have done wrong i will appreciate it soo much

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
//check email

if(empty($_POST['email_addr']))

$msg_email = "*";

$email_subject = $_POST['email_addr'];

$email_pattern = '/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/';

preg_match($email_pattern, $email_subject, $email_matches);

if(!$email_matches[0])

$msg2_email = "Please enter a valid email address";

}

// validation complete 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

if($msg_name=="" && $msg2_name=="" && $msg_email=="" && $msg2_email=="")

$msg_success = "Thankyou for your enquiry";

//send mail   

$EmailFrom = "someone@somewhere.com";

$EmailTo = "someone@somewhere.com";

$Subject = "Online contact form";

$email_addr = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email_addr'])); 

} 

// prepare email body text

$Body = "";

$Body .= "email_addr: ";

$Body .= $email_addr;

$Body .= "\n";

// send email 

$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: $EmailFrom");

    ?>
```

Comment: Set up a Boolean variable with a default status of false. When you validate properly, set that variable to true. If that variable is true, the form validated properly, so send the email.

Comment: Are you able to provide an example? I have literally just been follwing a tutorias - [http://www.w3resource.com/php/form/php-form-validation.php] and trying to learn along the way but its hard when you havent had much experience with php and are given a week to have a website finished :p

Answer (score 2):

I would **not** use your regular expression to validate email addresses. I'd use filter_var instead.

```
if( !filter_var($_POST['email_addr'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
    $msg2_email = "Please enter a valid email address";
}
```

`filter_var` returns false if the filter fails, otherwise it returns the filtered email address.

On top of that, you can set a `default` value if your filter fails. For example, suppose that the email address field is not necessary, so instead writing yet another line of code to check for null-ness in your variables like:

```
$isEmailNull =  ( $_POST['email_addr'] === NULL) ? NULL : $_POST['email_addr'];
```

with `filter_var` you can write it like:

```
$emailAddress =  filter_var( $_POST['email_addr'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL, 
                              array('options' => array(
                                          'default' => null
                                          )
                                   ));
```

If your filter fails, then `$emailAddress` is not false, but null. Which makes more sense for non-boolean variables.

You can read more about `filter_var` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

you can validate/sanitize IP addresses, URLs, Email addresses, ASCII characters, numbers, etc... without using regular expressions that may or may not work.